# How do I activate The new folding that shows parameter names for method values

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

How do I activate the new function that shows parameter names for method values in IntelliJ 14?

[Notable changes in IntelliJ IDEA 14](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP)

I saw this function (and liked it!) in one of the EAPs, but it seems to have disappeared from my IDE in the official release of IntelliJ 14.

Thanks
/Markus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding | Inline parameter names for literal call arguments

Comment: It needed a restart as well after changing this setting. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, editor reopening is sufficient. It's a known bug, which you can vote/watch: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131638