# Java 8 named parameter passing?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm watching this video:

```
https://vimeo.com/131394616
```

and in minute `51:51` a method `loadTag(String tag, /* other args */)` is called with the following syntax:

```
loadTag(
  tag: "java",
  /* other args */
);
```

is this simply a feature of his IDE? Now that we're on the subject, is there a way to achieve named parameter passing in Java (8)?

Edit: note that I'm my follow-up question about a named parameter passing idiom for Java is not my main concern, but the actual syntax which used in the video which does not compile in my IDE.

Comment: AFAIK, no there isn't

Comment: No that's not java, maybe Scala..

Comment: I think it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800827/how-do-i-activate-the-new-folding-that-shows-parameter-names-for-method-values

Comment: The second question, linked by @zapl, seems to refer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the video you can later see the parameters go back to normal form, so it's some sort of IDE plugin/tool/macro (looks like IntelliJ IDEA, which has a lot of these) to display it in that form.

I can definitely see the advantage in a demonstration situation like that, so while it's not available in the current Java version, who knows what future will bring.